# Math.max are there some Syntax errors I'm not seeing?

Tags: java, math, compiler-errors

These lines are the culprit:
I was getting negative numbers so I decided to use the Math.max to ensure that the results would be no less than 0, but now I'm getting errors. My search just found me this method to use, but is there some particular Syntax I need in this form?

```
x.hp-=Math.max(0,(y.atk-x.def));
y.hp-=Math.max(0,(x.atk-y.def));
```

Everything works now, Thanks. 
The incorrect edit was due to a redundant ( opening parentheses.

Comment: *What* errors are you getting?

Comment: you **SHOULD NOT** delete your previous code in the question and replace with the updated one!

Comment: There are no missing semi-colons in what's left of your code after you vandalised your own question. It is therefore unanswerable, and of zero permanent value, as the existing answers, including mine, address a different state of the question. Voted to close.

Comment: Is there for a way for me to close it myself? I was careless. Sorry guys. I'll be more mindful in the future, ironically enough I thought it'd make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to other answers here,

```
(Math.max(0,(y.atk-x.def))
```

has an *extra* parenthesis, at the beginning. Remove it:

```
Math.max(0,(y.atk-x.def))
```

You can indeed put an extra pair around the whole thing, as you have started to do, and as other answers appear to insist is necessary, but it isn't. It's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`)` is missing in for Math.max method.  i.e `(Math.max(0,(y.atk-x.def)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Math.max(0,(x.atk-y.def)))
(Math.max(0,(y.atk-x.def)))
```

end both with " `)` "